# How do I contain the size of responsive google ad?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this responsive google ad code which I use to place in my website to show ads.

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-REMOVED"
     data-ad-slot="REMOVED"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

However, when I place the snippet, it shows a MASSIVE ad. I only want to give google ads a space of `1000px` width and `100px` height to place an ad in. Then it can be responsive within that area. I tried creating a `div` box of `max-height:100px;` and `max-width:100px` to contain the ad in the space I mentioned but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? I am also using bootstrap, so if possible to keep the answer in bootstrap, that would be great too, if not that's okay.

```
<div class="row gutter-vr-30px align-items-center">
    <div class="col text-center h-100">
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-REMOVED"
             data-ad-slot="REMOVED"
             data-ad-format="auto"
             data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        <script>
             (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to illustrate what I believe your problem is. A parent element having max-height or max-width has no effect on a child element's ability to grow outside those bounds.

I don't have personal experience including google ads, but it may be that you need to set the size of the ad on Google's end. There may be a way for you to specify what the script renders on your page on your AdSense account, but I don't believe it will be possible just with html/css.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#d1,
#d3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#d2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#d4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="d3">
    <div id="d4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```